# Failed to start ElasticSearch - Could not find plugin class

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

We have an existing java based custom plugin for ElasticSearch. We now upgraded to ElasticSearch 2.1.1 and added plugin-descriptor.properties files to point to our plugin class.

After that, we were able to install our custom plugin. But when we start ElasticSearch service, it is unable to find this custom plugin. We verified that the class file is present under the /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/ directory.

Following is the exception stack trace:

```
[2016-01-20 13:13:48,527][ERROR][bootstrap] Exception
ElasticsearchException[Could not find plugin class [com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins]]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins];
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginClass(PluginsService.java:382)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:348)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:109)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:146)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:128)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginClass(PluginsService.java:380)
        ... 8 more
[2016-01-20 13:22:55,236][INFO ][node                     ] [localhost] version[2.1.1], pid[20680], build[40e2c53/2015-12-15T13:05:55Z]
[2016-01-20 13:22:55,237][INFO ][node                     ] [localhost] initializing ...
[2016-01-20 13:22:55,840][ERROR][bootstrap                ] Exception
ElasticsearchException[Could not find plugin class [com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins.class]]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins.class];
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginClass(PluginsService.java:382)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:348)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:109)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:146)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:128)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginClass(PluginsService.java:380)
        ... 8 more
```

Following is the content of our plugin-descriptor.properties

```
description=EDP Custom Plugins
version=${project.version}
name=edpCustomPlugins
jvm=true
site=false
classname=com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins
java.version=${java.specification.version}
elasticsearch.version=2.1.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be that you packaged the plugin incorrectly.

Perhaps you are trying to install the jar file with the compiled classes instead of a installing a zip file that contains both the jar file and the plugin-descriptor.properties file.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. After putting them in a zip file, server is booting up fine. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I was doing the same mistake... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your class name should be com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins.class. This class part at the end seems strange. I guess your class name is com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins. Another thing... can you open jar file which you've built and see if there is class com.symc.edp.elasticsearch.plugin.CustomEDPPlugins inside?

Comment: Corrected the typo, there is no .class in the end of classname property.

Also, I verified that the class file is present both in the jar file as well as under the elasticsearch plugins/edpCustomPlugins directory.

Comment: Another thing I notice is that it is not copying the jar along with plugin-descriptor.properties file. It is exploding the jar under plugins/edpCustomPlugin folder.